# Published .Net Core App Warns to Install .Net Core but it's Already Installed

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, publishing, .net-core-3.1

I made a WPF and Console application for someone to use on their private server which I can't have access to. I used Visual Studio 2019's built-in "Publishing Wizard" to create Framework Dependant single-file apps. When the person opened the WPF app they were greeted with the standard warning:

[image: A message box displaying the warning To run this application, you must install .Net Core. Would you like to download it now?]

They clicked yes and to my understanding, they installed .Net Core 3.1 which is what the applications target.

After they restarted the computer they got the exact same warning again. I wasn't sure what was going on so I repackaged the apps as self-contained since the installed version of .Net Core was the same as what my applications were targeting.

That seemed to work for a little bit. We ran into some unrelated issues that I had to fix in the code on my end and then I re-published the projects and sent them out.

They tried to use the WPF application and they got the install warning again.

Now no matter what combination of options I pick in the "Publish Wizard" they keep getting the warning.

I'm not sure what to do.

Here's a picture of my publish settings

[image: A picture describing the Profile Settings for publishing the WPF application.]

Comment: Have you tried it on any other Computers? Any Virtual Machines? Because if it only happens on one, it is propably something majorly wrong with that Computer. Might need a Windows reinstallation.

Comment: Sadly no, I can ask the person to try that but it's out of my hands.

Comment: This guy is running a Server, but obviously was incapable of giving you a proper screenshoot. That is a Phone Camera image - and also so zoomed in, we can not be sure if anything else is written on that message box. So I really suspect the issue is on his side.

Comment: Simply hitting the `PrtScn` (Print Screen) button will take a screenshot of the desktop. Hitting `Ctrl+C` on a dialog box will copy the title, full text *and* button text. Right now, we can't even guess what the error message is - does the title ask for a *different* runtime version perhaps?

Comment: They should also run `dotnet --version` and send the result.

Comment: It's so weird. The title is just the app name, they tried it on their server and laptop with the same warning popping up again, they ran `dotnet --version` and the server is running `3.1.100` and the laptop was running `3.0.100`.

For now I'm going to extract the logic into a .Net Framwork solution instead to get it up and going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the fact that the applications were targeting win-x86 and the user only had access to 64-bit runtimes of .Net Core.

For some reason, I thought it would be able to handle a 32-bit version even if it was running 64-bit runtimes.

I guess live and learn.

Comment: Did you try to install .Net Core 32 bit runtime? I did try this, but it was not helpful at all...

Comment: @RudolfJan I'm going to assume I just targeted a 64-bit build, it's been a long time since this happened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It still is confusing, but I think I got a working solution now, without really understanding what is going on...  There is Publish option that allows to set a publish profile. It creates a long list of dll's to include, no idea why this is necessary and it provides a number of options for deployment. I may want to write down what I understand of it and then check if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @But is It NetCore was included in your Self Content published file?

Comment: Dellos, this happened in 2019, I don't remember anything about this project.

Comment: I have two x86 apps. One works, the other doesn't. I wonder what is missing.

Comment: Oops, turns out my other project accidentally references ASP.NET Core which is not used.

Answer (score 13):

In my case I had the same issue, and the problem was that I was not deploying the file "MY_PROGRAM_NAME.runtimeconfig.json". After copying this file, which is present in the build output, the application is launched without problems.

Comment: I agree this is one of the things you need to do, but even if I do, it does not always help me out.

Comment: Exactly my issue, thanks. Do you know why? X

Comment: No, in my case it's already deployed.