# .net core Console Application asking to install .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-10, .net-core-3.1

We have a .net core console application which targets the 3.1 framework.  The target runtime is win x-64
(See image)

[image]

The application has been installed onto a 64 bit windows 10 machine, runs on start up, and has been successfully running for 2 weeks.  There have been no changes to the application,  however, today,  the user is now presented with a request to install the .net Core framework.

[image]

We have ran dotnet --info on the machine, and the framework is still there :-

[image]

We have even tried logging off, restarting and still getting prompted when the machine starts.
Has anyone else experienced this? Im not quite sure what else to try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367037/published-net-core-app-warns-to-install-net-core-but-its-already-installed

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you, i have seen this, and been through the responses, however, my situation is difference,  This application HAS been successfully running for 2 weeks,  and has only just suddenly stopped.  The Target set is the target that the application has being installed on.

Comment: Your application is framework depend, so maybe someone or something changed environment variables or other stuff which instruments how application can find runtime?